# Pythonic "or" operation

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison-operators

In python I can write an expression like `3 < a < 10` and it gets evaluated with an `and` condition.

That is, `3 < a < 10`  is a syntactic sugar for: `3 < a and a < 10`

Is there a similar pythonic way to write it as an `or` condition?

Comment: probably `match ... case A|B` will fit your needs

Comment: Operator chaining only works one way, and you've identified it.  No similar shortcut for `or`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`a < 3 or a > 10` is what I would write.

If you had `3 >= a or a >= 10` you could use [de Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) to turn the `or` into an `and`, resulting in `not (3 < a < 10)`.

For the specific case of checking if a number is out of range you could use `a not in range(3, 11)`. A neat trick, but the `11` being off by one bugs me. I'd stick with `or`, myself.

Comment: Smart use of de Morgan's!! I would stick with `or` as well though. For clarity, its good to avoid negations if possible.